# How can I show this map is bijective?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've seen the following problem:

> $\sim$ is an equivalence relation given by:
>
> - $(0,y)\sim (1,y)$ for all $y\in [0,1]$
> - $(x,0)\sim (x,1)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$
> - $(x,y)\sim (x,y)$ for all $x,y\in (0,1)\times (0,1)$.
>
> $P=([0,1] \times [0,1])/ \sim$
>
> $N=\{(x,y,z\in \Bbb{R}\; :\; (x^2+y^2-2)^2+z^2 =1 \}$
>
> Consider the map: $h:P\to N$ given by:
>
> $$h(\overline{(x,y)})=(\sqrt{2+\cos(2 \pi x)} \cos(2\pi y),\;\sqrt{2+\cos(2 \pi x)} \sin (2\pi y),\;\sin(2\pi y))$$

How can I show this map is bijective? I suspect this uses stuff a little bit beyond what I know. For injectivity, I thought I could prove it showing it is injective component wise but that doesn't hold for some of these functions. I'm stuck.

Comment: Before you go and write a formal proof, does it make sense to you that $N$ is a sphere? Next, does it make sense what the equivalence classes of $\sim$ are? Finally, does it make sense that taking the quotient of $[0,1]^2$ by the equivalence relation $\sim$ should also give you a sphere (in some sense)? The "point" of this exercise is to make precise the idea that the quotient $[0,1]^2/\sim$ is also a sphere (at least at the level of sets).

Comment: Isn't it the case that $h(0.25, y)=h(0.75, y)$, but $(0.25, y)\not\sim (0.75, y)$, so $h$ is not injective?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Isn't it a [torus-like object?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5E2%2By%5E2-2%29%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D1)

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right. Sorry about that! Please imagine I said "torus" instead of "sphere" in my comment. Apologies for the confusion, I glanced over your post too quickly.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yes. I see it is a torus, when you cross some boundary, you end up in the other side. So, the idea is that if we map an entire torus into an entire torus, this mapping must be bijective?

Comment: There are non-bijective maps between tori, but the point here is that by recognizing both sets as tori, we can produce an "interesting" bijection. This bijection $h$ has some geometric content -- it sends "longitudinal" circles in $P$ to "longitudinal" circles in $N$, and "latitudinal" circles in $P$ to "latitudinal" circles in $N$. In fact, this is how $h$ was created -- the complicated formula you were given was produced by thinking about how to write down a function that sends longitudinal/latitudinal circles in $P$ to corresponding circles in $N$.

Comment: @A.M. The $z$-coordinate of $h(0.25,y)$ is $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$, but the $z$-coordinate of $h(0.75,y)$ is $\sin(3\pi/2) = -1$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk the $z$-coordinate is $\sin(2\pi y)$, not $\sin(2\pi x)$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk But what is that interesting bijection? I think I still don't get it. Do we try to think about these longitudinal and latitudinal circles? By fixing $y$ and $x$?